# Python Finite Difference Schemes for 1D Heat Equation: How to express for loop using numpy expression

Tags: finite-difference, python, fluid-dynamics, numpy, heat-transfer

**Hello all,**

I've recently been introduced to Python and Numpy, and am still a beginner in applying it for numerical methods. I've been performing simple 1D diffusion computations. I suppose my question is more about applying python to differential methods. I'm asking it here because maybe it takes some diff eq background to understand my problem.

***My overall question :*** *Pretty beginner question, I have a picture of a specific example case below.*

What are the benefits/cons of using built-in numpy functions vs using for loops in numerical computational methods (CFD & FEA), is it absolutely necessary to write explicit for loops for time stepping sometimes? *(no pun intended)*

I attached a link to the short excercise I've been practicing below. Thanks for your time!

---

### **Discretization Scheme**

*

**Discretization**

*
[image: Discretized 1D diffusion eqn, FWD time, Centered Space]

---

**My specific code example**: How could you get rid of the for loop below ?

---

[image: for loop]

---

The link for the excercise :

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/blob/master/lessons/04_spreadout/04_01_Heat_Equation_1D_Explicit.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numpy arrays and methods are incredibly helpful. They are usually optimized and much faster than looping in python. Always look for a way to use an existing numpy method for your application.

`np.roll()` will allow you to shift and then you just add.

I learned to use `convolve()` from comments on [How to np.roll() faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32195525/3904031). I haven't checked if this is faster or not, but it may depend on the number of dimensions. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363868/83380) for a 2D relaxation of the Laplace equation (electrostatics, a different problem)

For this kind of relaxation you'll need a bounding box, so the boolean `do_me` is `False` on the boundary.

I know that for Jacobi relaxation solutions to the Laplace equation, there are two speed-up methods. I don't know if they can be extended to solving the Heat Diffusion equation, but I'm sure something can be done:

- [Multigrids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigrid_method); solve on a coarse (fast) grid, then interpolate to a fine grid and iterate a little longer
- [Successive Overrelaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation); "overshoot" the averaging by changing the values by an amount larger than 100% of what you would have with simple averaging. Try values like 110% to 150%, it can go unstable if they are too large.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

T0             = np.zeros(50, dtype=float)
T0[17:25]      = 1.

T1             = T0.copy()  # method 1  np.roll()
T2             = T0.copy()  # method 2  convolve()

do_me          = np.ones_like(T0, dtype=bool)
do_me[[0, -1]] = False    #  keep the boundaries of your bounding box fixed

a              = 0.01

hold_1         = [T0.copy()]
for i in range(10001):
    Ttemp      = T1 + a*(np.roll(T1, +1) + np.roll(T1, -1) - 2*T1)
    T1[do_me]  = Ttemp[do_me]
    if not i%1000:
        hold_1.append(T1.copy())

hold_2         = [T0.copy()]
kernel         = np.array([a, (1 - 2.*a), a])

for i in range(10001):
    Ttemp      = convolve(T2, kernel)
    T2[do_me]  = Ttemp[do_me]
    if not i%1000:
        hold_2.append(T2.copy())

if True:
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    for thing in hold_1:
        plt.plot(thing)

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    for thing in hold_2:
        plt.plot(thing)

    plt.show()
```