# Simple, easy to install and use Python FEM solver (and example) for 2D cylindrical Laplace equation

Tags: finite-element, software-recommendation

In my earlier question [Interpolating the gradient of a cylindrically symmetric potential field expected obey the Laplace equation, especially near/across r=0](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/32784/17869) I give a simple example of a Jacobi relaxation script - the Laplace equation is solved for a cylindrically symmetric electrostatic lens system. The symmetry reduces the problem to 2 dimensions.

I am *reading and learning* about FEM and rather than write my own I would like to start with an existing package to solve the same cylindrical lens problem (ideally in 2D for speed) with all [Dirichlet boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) (i.e. I define the potential on all surfaces and boundaries).

I have seen [PySfe](https://sfepy.org/doc-devel/index.html), [pyGIMLi](https://www.pygimli.org/_tutorials_auto/2_modelling/plot_2-mod-fem.html), [Fenics](https://fenicsproject.org/) and [Firedrake](https://www.firedrakeproject.org/documentation.html) and [scikit-fem](https://scikit-fem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) Most if not all of these have good examples for Laplace in 2D but these are cartesian examples.

**What I need** is

1. **A recommendation** for a package that is easy to install (I'm not a developer, I can spell "pip" and "conda" (barely) but not much more) and will have some way to generate solutions I can compare directly with my Jacobi relaxation work.
2. Advice how to modify the (likely present) Laplace example for the problem as 2D cylindrical, i.e. $\phi(r, z)$ and $\theta$-independent.

Ideally I'll set up the problem in an IDE and run from a command line. I'm using macOS with an Anaconda installation.

---

From the linked question

[image: Laplace equation Jacobi relaxation for cylindrical lens]

Comment: Please provide the actual equations that you would like to solve and the necessary boundary conditions instead of a reference to your previous experimentation with this problem.

Comment: @Konstantinos if I'm not mistaken (it's 2:30 AM here) [Laplace's equation expressed in cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation#Forms_in_different_coordinate_systems) with no $\theta$ dependence will be $$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}  + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{dz^2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide all the details so I made some assumptions. First, assuming symmetry in $\theta$, the Laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates reads
$$\partial_r^2 u + \frac{1}{r} \partial_r u + \partial^2_z u = 0.$$
Let $\Omega = (0, 1)^2$ where the variables are $(r,z)$.
The symmetry boundary is $\Gamma_0 = \{ (r, z) : r = 0 \}$
and the remaining part is $\Gamma_1 = \partial \Omega \setminus \Gamma_0$.
We consider the boundary conditions
$$\partial_n u|_{\Gamma_0} = 0, \quad u|_{\Gamma_1} = g$$
for given boundary data $g$.

For testing, an analytical solution is given by the Bessel function of the first kind $J_0$, see [a question on another forum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509932/solving-laplace-equation-in-cylindrical-coordinates-with-azimuthal-symmetry). In particular,
$$J_0(r)(\exp(z) + \exp(-z))$$
satisfies the above Laplace equation when
its restriction onto $\Gamma_1$ is used as $g$.

We define the function spaces
$$V_z = \{ w \in H^1(\Omega) : w|_{\Gamma_1} = z \}$$
for a given $z$.
The weak formulation reads: find $u \in V_g$ such that
$$\int_\Omega -\partial_r u \partial_r v + r^{-1} \partial_r u v - \partial_z u \partial_z v = 0 \quad \forall v \in V_0.$$

After `pip install scikit-fem==9.0.1` you can implement the weak formulation as follows:

```py
from skfem import *
from skfem.helpers import *

@BilinearForm
def laplace(u, v, w):
    r, z = w.x
    ur, uz = u.grad
    vr, vz = v.grad
    return - ur * vr + 1 / r * ur * v - uz * vz
```

Then you can solve the problem with the boundary data from the Bessel function:

```py
from scipy.special import jv

m = MeshTri().refined(4)
basis = Basis(m, ElementTriP1())
A = laplace.assemble(basis)

y = basis.project(lambda x: jv(0, x[0]) * (np.exp(x[1]) + np.exp(-x[1])))
x = solve(*condense(A, 0 * y, x=y, D=basis.get_dofs({'top', 'right', 'bottom'})))

basis.plot(x, shading='gouraud', colorbar=True).show()
```

If you have `matplotlib` installed, running the above code will result in the following figure:

[image: Solution to the cylindrical Laplace equation.]

You can also plot the difference `x - y` to see that the error is small:

[image: Pointwise error.]

I was a bit suspicious of the larger error at $r=0$ so I tried different mesh refinements to see that it converges as expected. I concluded that the error is probably due to the term with $1/r$ which warrants for more integration points or more elements near $r=0$.

(Note: I am the maintainer of scikit-fem.)

Comment: This is exactly what I need to get started. I spent yesterday at the library reading books and viewing online material but found myself saying "OK I believe you, very rigorous, but how do I *do it?*" A quick installation question; yesterday I'd already used `pip install scikit-fem` and `pip install meshio` (I have matplotlib from my anaconda installation) and while your example runs fine, `skfem.__version__` yields 8.1.0 If I use your command for 9.0.1 and add ` -U` should that bring me up to date?

Comment: Yes, that should work.